# Visual Studio hangs on "Begin package load [Visual Studio Source Control Integration Package]"

Tags: visual-studio

It takes almost full minute to load this:

- 56  Begin package load [Visual Studio Source Control Integration Package] {53544C4D-E3F8-4AA0-8195-8A8D16019423}  VisualStudio 2014/10/14 **15:27:31.109**
- 57  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {8D316614-311A-48F4-85F7-DF7020F62357}  VisualStudio 2014/10/14 **15:28:28.380**

Besides this there are all kinds of other problems with this installation of Visual Studio, with a lot of hangs and other behaviour.

- Can anyone tell me what this Package includes? I am using Perforce as source control. Do I still need this package?
- How can I remove this package/feature to see if it solves all my other problems?

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having issues loading the plugin.  Which version of P4VS are you using?   Please confirm so I can better troubleshoot your issue. Also, you should be able to disable (not remove) P4VS via:  Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Installed -> All, highlight P4VS and click [Disable]

Comment: By the way if you are having memory issues and using 2014.2 P4VS, you can downgrade to P4VS 2014.1. If you do so, you would need to remove the 2014.2 version first.

Comment: Hi P4Shimada, in the end it didn't seem to be the Perforce plugin in this case, see the answer below. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had Fusion Logging still enabled, and this created a huge slowdown in everything. Disabling the logging fixed my problem.